# difference between requirements documents specification document and requirement specification document

Tags: testing, specifications, requirements

A google search gave me the following definitions

Requirements document what is needed - they shouldn't specify the how, but the what.

Specifications document how to achieve the requirements - they should specify the how.

then what is requirement specification document...

can you please clarify me with examples I didnt have any experiennce with this, I started to gain knowledge in testing,

And also what documents are needed to start writing testcases....

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The sound-bite answer is that requirements are what your program should do, the specifications are how you plan to do it.

Another way to look at it is that the requirements represent the application from the perspective of the user, or the business as a whole. The specification represents the application from the perspective of the technical team. Specifications and requirements roughly communicate the same information, but to two completely different audiences.

Comment: then what requirement specification document contains? I heard this word many times...